# Need to make certain components only view access based on new role?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

In the app I'm working on it's a fairly big codebase and components/pages are sometimes based on user roles. Admins will be able to see certain buttons or sections while regular users are not.

I need to modify a lot of the existing pages/components to accommodate a new role that's being added, which is view-only-admin.

This role will only be able to see everything including calendars, tasks, etc. but they are not allowed to make any sort of updates.

It would be a tremendous amount of work to go through the template of each component and file and look for v-if admin and also add a view-only-admin as well as make every single button or submit/click method behave differently for a view-only-admin role.

What would be the best way to handle this for the entire app? Re-writing and modifying v-if and submit methods seem like a bad use of time.

I've only been working with Vue/Nuxt for a few months, but I have read Mixins are pieces of code that you can reuse.

Would it be possible to write a mixin so that if the role is "view-only-admin" and there's an action that is a put/Post call, then they are not able to perform those API calls and presented with an error message?

I'm not sure how to go about properly implementing this feature. If I am able to stop all PUT/POST calls using a mixin, it would just redirect to a 404 right?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using axios for POST/PUT methods, then you should definitely check [Interceptors](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors).

But if you add only an interceptors without UI updates - your users may be confused why some buttons exist but doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Yes using axios with Vuex. I will look at interceptors that is new to me. I may be able to add a Toast Message that says "user does not have valid permissions"

Comment: I was able to set up an interceptor with a simple console.log in my nuxt app and it's working! However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to get to the store. Currently under plugin/axios.js I have an interceptor function. export default function ({ $axios, redirect, store }) {
  $axios.interceptors.request.use(
    function (config) {
      // Do something before request is sent
      console.log('before sending...' + store)
      return config
    }
  )
}

store is being console.log as [object][object] 
How can I get to store/user/getter for the viewOnlyAdmin getter?

Comment: I was able to use axios interceptors and nuxt context with a mix of store.state to block all POST/PUT requests for view only roles. Thanks